# Soft Memory Limit Exceeded while serving large files with Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I continually hit "Soft Private memory Limit Exceeded" errors while attempting to serve large streaming video files an Appengine Instance (running django 1.5).

Sample Code:

```
def stream_file(request, blob_key):
    blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=1048576)
    content_type = 'video/mp4'

    return http.StreamingHttpResponse(blob_reader, content_type=content_type)
```

My example serves via [blobstore api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore) but I've experienced the same problem using the [GCS Lib](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions) + building my own generator function.

**How can I efficiently serve large files without exceeding the soft memory limit?**

Comment: This is interesting. How are you streaming the response? Won't you get a timeout on the request?

Comment: There is no streaming response from GAE.  Everything is held in memory until the end of the request.

Comment: @TimHoffman That's interesting - the Docs would seem to indicate that I could read a buffer. See ```read_buffer_size``` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open

Comment: The docs you are reading are about cloud storage client.  Standard Appengine functionality has no capability for streaming irrespective of what a library might try and implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed that you are reading the blob into memory and then sending it out.  have you considered using a handler that sends directly from blobstore?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because that was ultimately how I solved this issue.  The problem remains that the GCS client seems to have a memory leak, as attempting to return a streaming data object would consistently cause a problem.